# If a checkbox is selected, select two others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The table contains a few rows like that:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="indicator[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to disable `'graduations'` being checked if `'indicator'` is not checked. And if checked, i need to check exactly two `'graduations'` in that row.

My actual code only limits the number of checked `'graduations'`.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name=graduations\\[\\]]').click(function() {
        if($(this).parent().siblings().children("input[name=graduations\\[\\]]:checkbox:checked").length >= 2)
            this.checked = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: By saying "I need to check exactly two `graduations` in that row, does it mean you have to set up a lock so that the user cannot proceed further if 2 are not checked, or just limit the choice to 2 checks?

Comment: The user cannot send the form if exists a checked `indicator` without two `graduations`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("#area_covered").click(function(){
    if($("#area_covered").is(':checked'))
        $('.area_covered').prop('checked', true);
    else
        $('.area_covered').prop('checked', false);  
});
```

give some id to the checkbox you're going to click, and give some class to both of the other checkboxes which you want to be get checked also.
then use the above jquery tag, which would work for you definitely.\

Thanks & Enjoy coding :)

Comment: `if-else` can be simplified into `$('.area_covered').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))`;

Comment: perfect solution for the problem. +1

Comment: The form contains a dynamic number of rows similar to that. This solution only works for one row. Right?

Answer (score -1):

Updated try this simple [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t1vu1ara/1/)

```
 $(function(){
    $("input[name^=graduations]").on("change",function(e){
        if((!$("input[name^=indicator]").is(":checked")) || +$("input[name^=graduations]:checked").length > 2 ){
              $(this).prop('checked',false);
        }
        
    });
     
});
```

makes it simple

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes. But i need a validation that don't leave rows with none or less than 2 graduations selected.